# Duplicate rows to expand date into week?

Tags: r

I have a data frame `a` that I'm trying to merge with data frame `b`. Data frame `a` and data frame `b` both have a column called `date` that are both date types. `date` in data frame `a` contains only the last day of the week because the data is a weekly summary of `pop`. `date` in data frame `b` is an individual date because the data is a daily summary of `cars`.

Since I'd like to merge `a` and `b` to do some analysis of daily cars for the population, I would like to expand the `date` column in `a` and create duplicate rows for each day in the week.

i.e. I start off with the data frame `a` below

```
      pop       date 
1   10002 2020-07-12 
2   10025 2020-07-19 
3   10102 2020-07-26
```

and turn it into the data frame `a_mod` below

```
      pop       date 
1   10002 2020-07-06
2   10002 2020-07-07 
3   10002 2020-07-08 
4   10002 2020-07-09 
5   10002 2020-07-10 
6   10002 2020-07-11 
7   10002 2020-07-12 
8   10025 2020-07-13 
9   10025 2020-07-14 
...
```

then merge `a_mod` and `b` together to look like this

```
      pop       date cars 
1   10002 2020-07-06  252 
2   10002 2020-07-07   46 
3   10002 2020-07-08   43 
4   10002 2020-07-09   44
```

Any idea how I can achieve this? I'm stumped.

ETA: I later figured out this was not the best idea, since I really only just wanted to map values from `a` onto `b` rather than blow up my data frames with so many rows. Instead, I [asked a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325752/condense-and-join-data-frame/64325832#64325832) and got a different technique that worked much better. Thank you to all who took the time to help!

Comment: Use function `floor_date()` from package `lubridate` to get the end-of-week date for data.frame `b`.  Then merge `a` and `b` by that end-of-week date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways (depending on how you want to go).

Using `ceiling_date()` on `b`.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

b %>%
  mutate(date2 = ceiling_date(date, 
                              unit = "weeks", 
                              week_start = 1)) %>% # 1 for Monday, 7 for Sunday
  inner_join(a %>% rename(date2 = date)) %>%
  select(pop, date, cars)
```

Modifying `a`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mod_a <- data.frame(date = seq(min(b$date), max(b$date), by = "days") %>%
  left_join(a) %>%
  fill(pop, .direction = "updown")
mod_a %>% inner_join(b)
```

Comment: thank you so much, this looks like it should work but I am getting an error when modifying `a`, it says `Error in UseMethod("left_join") :    no applicable method for 'left_join' applied to an object of class "Date"`. ETA: could this be due to the fact that not every date in b appears in a?

Comment: @carousallie - I am not sure if that is the issue. The `left_join()` is designed to work with this situation where some data is in one set but not the other.

Comment: I saw someone else with this same error, but not sure I understand either code enough to know how to fix. Any advice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909508/dplyr-left-join-with-timeline-and-dates