# Condense and join data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that I'm trying to merge with another, and I'm having some issues that I believe trace back to the fact that each observation is an incident rather than a cumulative amount. I have the data frame below where each row is an individual observation, and I'll then use the `week` and the `code` to merge it with another data frame based on the same variables `week` and `code`.

data frame `a` has each row as a specific observation, but I need it to become a cumulative observation/row by code/date. I'm completely stumped.

```
  date       count       code  week
  <date>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-06-07     4      13309    23
2 2020-06-07     5      13309    23
3 2020-07-12     6      18099    28
4 2020-07-12     8      18099    28
```

needs to become

```
  date       count       code  week
  <date>     <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-06-07     9      13309    23
2 2020-07-12    14      18099    28
```

Then, it will be able to be merged with data frame  `b`

```
  date       color     name       code  week
  <date>     <char>   <char>      <dbl> <dbl>
1 2020-06-07 Blue         A      13309    23
1 2020-06-07 Yellow       B      13309    23
1 2020-06-07 Purple       D      13309    23
3 2020-07-12 Yellow       A      18099    28
3 2020-07-12 Blue         E      18099    28
```

and the end result will be

```
  date       color     name     code   week    count
  <date>     <char>   <char>   <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2020-06-07 Blue         A    13309     23        9
1 2020-06-07 Yellow       B    13309     23        9
1 2020-06-07 Purple       D    13309     23        9
3 2020-07-12 Yellow       A    18099     28       14
3 2020-07-12 Blue         E    18099     28       14
```

I originally used the code below to do this, but it completely blew up my data frame. My dimensions went from `dim(a) == (209807, 86)` to `dim(merged) == (1367029, 89)`. I tried multiple types of joins (right, left, inner, etc.) but all of them still blew up the data frame (varied by a few 100 or so observations, but still resulted in well over a million rows). That's why I'm thinking the issue is due to `a` being each observation vs a summary observation for a specific code on a specific date.

```
merged <- right_join(x = b,
                     y = a, 
                     by = c("code" = "code",
                       "week" = "week"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
a %>%
  group_by(date, code, week) %>%
  summarize(count = sum(count)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(b, ., by = c("date", "code", "week"))
#         date  color name  code week count
# 1 2020-06-07   Blue    A 13309   23     9
# 2 2020-06-07 Yellow    B 13309   23     9
# 3 2020-06-07 Purple    D 13309   23     9
# 4 2020-07-12 Yellow    A 18099   28    14
# 5 2020-07-12   Blue    E 18099   28    14
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close with the call to `right_join()` but before that, the first thing you should do is to total the first data frame so you have a sum of the counts. You could do it manually with `summarize()` but an easier way is using a nested data frame and creating a new column that sums the counts.

Let me know if you need clarification?

Next time please post your data in a format that is easier to copy and paste into R.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dfA <- tribble(~date, ~count, ~code, ~week,
               "2020-06-07",     4,      13309,    23,
               "2020-06-07",     5,      13309,    23,
               "2020-07-12",     6,      18099,    28,
               "2020-07-12",     8,      18099,    28)

dfB <- tribble(~date, ~color, ~name, ~code, ~week,
               "2020-06-07", "Blue", "A", 13309, 23,
               "2020-06-07", "Yellow", "B", 13309, 23,
               "2020-06-07", "Purple", "D", 13309, 23,
               "2020-07-12", "Yellow", "A", 18099, 28,
               "2020-07-12", "Blue", "E", 18099, 28)

total_counts <- dfA %>% 
  group_by(date, code, week) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(count= map_dbl(data, sum)) %>% 
  select(date, count, code, week) %>% 
   right_join(dfB) %>% 
  select(date, color, name, code, week, count)
#> Joining, by = c("date", "code", "week")

total_counts

#> # A tibble: 5 x 6
#> # Groups:   date, code, week [2]
#>   date       color  name   code  week count
#>   <chr>      <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2020-06-07 Blue   A     13309    23     9
#> 2 2020-06-07 Yellow B     13309    23     9
#> 3 2020-06-07 Purple D     13309    23     9
#> 4 2020-07-12 Yellow A     18099    28    14
#> 5 2020-07-12 Blue   E     18099    28    14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using join by `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .(count = sum(count)), .(date, code, week)][b,
      on = .(date, code, week)]
#         date  code week count  color name
#1: 2020-06-07 13309   23     9   Blue    A
#2: 2020-06-07 13309   23     9 Yellow    B
#3: 2020-06-07 13309   23     9 Purple    D
#4: 2020-07-12 18099   28    14 Yellow    A
#5: 2020-07-12 18099   28    14   Blue    E
```